# how to create folder in dropbox using http ( with cUrl)

Tags: curl, dropbox-api

I am using dropbox API to create folder in my dropbox app account
below is my code but not creating folder on dropbox.

```
$url='https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/create_folder';
$post=array(
"path" => "/land/download" );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); 

$return_obj=json_decode($data);
```

Comment: What's the response from the server?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the relevant code? E.g., I don't see a call to `curl_exec `. What's the response from the API?

Comment: below is code,not get any response from server  `$url='https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/create_folder';
$post=array(
    "path" => "auto/land/download"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$return_obj=json_decode($data);

print_r($data);print_r($return_obj);`